# Casting to a type while in LINQ statement

Tags: .net, linq

I have the following LINQ in ASP.NET 4.0. I'm reading in my data through an XML file and trying to filter the results into a strongly typed object.

```
    List<Books> books = (from q in _XmlConnection.Descendants("BookShelf")
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Title = q.Element("title").Value,
                                        Author = q.Element("autor").Value
                                    }).ToList();
```

Now what I can do is run through a foreach after this statement and create a new Books object which is assigned to a list. What I would like to do though is contain all that in the LINQ statement, so that when I define a value for Title or Author, it's assigning it to List< Books > straight away. That way I can jump straight to "return books". Is there a way to do this?

(Note: The above code returns an error, but for now this is fine. I can use "var books" and it works ok, but I left it as this to show what I would like it to look like).

Cheers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there - right now you are projecting to an anonymous type (using `new {}` ) - to project to a class instance instead you need to specify the class name, so assuming your  `Book` class has public properties `Title` and `Author`:

```
List<Book> books = (from q in _XmlConnection.Descendants("BookShelf")
                                select new Book()
                                {
                                    Title = q.Element("title").Value,
                                    Author = q.Element("autor").Value
                                }).ToList();
```

Edit: Your example was using the type `Books` - I assume though that the class that holds the properties of a single book is named *Book* (singular).

Comment: That makes sense and it's working fine now. I was at least hoping it would be something tricky so wouldn't feel bad about being stuck ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Books> books = (from q in _XmlConnection.Descendants("BookShelf")
                                select new Book()
                                {
                                    Title = q.Element("title").Value,
                                    Author = q.Element("autor").Value
                                }).ToList();
```